# How to update jQuery value as you type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery QR Code generator that creates an image of a QR code based on the text you type into an `input`. The QR code and image source updates in real time as you alter your input.

What I need is to take the `src` of the image and place it in its own input that updates as you type. I was able to get the value of the `src` using this:

```
var imageSRC = $('.qr-preview img').attr('src');
$('input#code_img_src').val(imageSRC);
```

This works perfectly fine, however it only applies the value of the image when the PAGE LOADS, not each time the `img src` changes. Is there a way to make it so that every time the `src` changes that function updates in real time? I'm probably overlooking something simple here, and I've researched things like `setInterval` but I that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in all browsers, but this works in chrome:

```
$("#.qr-preview img").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    var imageSRC = $('.qr-preview img').attr('src');
    $('input#code_img_src').val(imageSRC);
});
```

Comment: I'm using chrome, and this didn't seem to have any effect. I tried this method after I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener

Comment: Try using on instead of bind?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are using a third-party jQuery plugin which you associate with an input and which generates the URL for a QR code for you, which it assigns to another image's `src` attribute. My answer assumes this is correct.

Let's say you have this input that the user types into, which modifies the QR code in real-time:

```
<input id="qr-input" type="text">
```

Then all you need to do is attach an event listener for the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) to this input, and in that listener, invoke the code to update the second input with the value of the image's `src` attribute:

```
function updateSrcInput() {
    var imageSRC = $('.qr-preview img').attr('src');
    $('input#code_img_src').val(imageSRC);
}

var timeoutId;
$('#qr-input').on('input', function () {
    if (timeoutId)
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(updateSrcInput, 0);
});
```

Note that I am using a timeout to make sure that the function runs after the plugin's code, and if multiple input events happen in a row (e.g. if the user is typing fast), only one call to your function will be made to update the other input, which means you're not doing wasted work.

If you need the second input to be correct on document load, just add a call to the `updateSrcInput()` function inside your document load function.

Comment: It's just set to document load right now, and that's why it's only doing it once when the page loads.

Comment: I re-read your question and think I may have a better answer for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try blur event for input. You can do like this:

```
 $('input#code_img_src').blur(function(){
    var imageSRC = $('.qr-preview img').attr('src');
    $(this).val(imageSRC);
 })
```